# Error on Create Plugin for telescope OctoberCMS

Tags: laravel, octobercms

Hello I'm trying to build a plugin for manage Telescope on my app built with OctoberCms, but when I use the Gate facade I have this error:

```
Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate] is not instantiable.
```

In my Plugin I'm trying simply this:

```
class Plugin extends PluginBase
{

    public function boot(){

        Gate::define('viewTelescope', function ($user) {
            return in_array($user->email, [
                //
            ]);
        });
    }
    public function registerComponents()
    {
    }

    public function registerSettings()
    {
    }
}
```

Initially I have tried to put

```
App::register(TelescopeServiceProvider::class);
```

But the error was same.

Comment: hmm `telescope` is a package did you installed it using composer in your plugin correctly, just for confirmation

Comment: Yes! I've installed with composer and I have in vendor, but When I try to make php artisan telescope:install or a general php artisan i get the error.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution.
My problem was that I should register also AuthServiceProvider.

So now:

```
class Plugin extends PluginBase
{

    public function boot(){

        $this->app->register(\Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class);
        $this->app->register(\Laravel\Telescope\TelescopeServiceProvider::class);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: ok nice ! I thought same first as they must be adding proper `Gate` class to have `define` method